# How can I truncate table overflow at a row boundary?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a table within a div that can have arbitrary rows. Sometimes the rows expand to accommodate more than one line of text. The div has a fixed height and overflow:hidden.

My question is, is it possible to truncate the table such that the overflow occurs on a row boundary?

For example, is there a way to make this:

[image: Bad]

Look like this:

[image: Good]

The main catch is that this *must not* use Javascript. Is this possible in HTML/CSS? I could do something in the code-behind (ASP.NET Webforms) if necessary, although I'd like to avoid it.

It has to work in IE7 and IE8. The number of rows displayed is not fixed - it depends on how many rows overflow with extra text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't shave off the row that's specifically being clipped by the `div`'s overflow unless you put on that JavaScript magic hat. CSS doesn't know about how your content is being rendered, or not — that's up to the browser to figure out.

You can hide every row that comes after an arbitrary row instead by doing something like this:

```
#somediv #sometable tr:nth-child(5) ~ tr {
    display: none;
}
```

The only real issue is that while `~` is supported by IE7 and newer, only IE9 supports `:nth-child()`. You could work around that by stacking multiple `+` combinators, but you end up with a rather long selector:

```
#somediv #sometable tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr ~ tr {
    display: none;
}
```

If there are too many rows in your table, limiting the number of rows in your page's code-behind may be better, as you'll save some bandwidth by shaving off those extra couple hundred bytes that'd otherwise be transmitted but never seen.

Comment: Eek sorry there are a couple of caveats I forgot in the OP. It has to work in IE7 and IE8. The number of rows displayed is not fixed - it depends on how many rows overflow with extra text. Thanks for your help, this is certainly closer to what I need.

Comment: Oh yeah and bandwidth/performance is not an issue but thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: @Martin: The one with lots of `+`s works in IE7+, but with CSS and `screen` styles you can only pick an arbitrary row and truncate from there.